# Can you place "so" after an adjective for emphasis?

Tags: adjectives

Normally you write, for example,

```
Life is so fleeting.
She's so beautiful.
```

"so" is used for emphasis.  Can you invert it with an adjective to have more emphasis?

```
Life is fleeting so.
She's beautiful so.
```

I think I have seen this kind of use before.  Note this question is for written, literary English, not spoken English.

Thank you.

Comment: What do you [deduce](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=is+beautiful+so%2Cis+so+beautiful&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cis%20beautiful%20so%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cis%20so%20beautiful%3B%2Cc0)?

Comment: You might be thinking of a usage like *It is better so.*  In this case, *so* is a synonym for *thus*, and the sentence means something like *It is better this way*.  But it's not just an emphatic version of *It is better.*

Answer (score 3):

No, Zack.  You shouldn't do that. Not even in "literary" English.  Moreover, "life" in English (even the "literary" kind) is neither "she" nor "he".

Comment: I don't think Zack meant to imply that life is gendered. Those are separate examples.

Comment: Yes, they're meant as separate sentences.  Unrelated.  I should have put a newline to make this more clear.

Comment: I don't mean to derail the original topic, but you certainly can personify the abstract concept of "life" and attribute gender to it.